# Flutter Directory path and Directory create path are different

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-device-explorer

**It's very odd**, when I call `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` it returns the following path:

> /data/user/0/co.XXX.dev/app_flutter

While running `(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).create(recursive: true)` creates a new folder at the above path:

> /data/data/co.XXX.dev/app_flutter

According to Android Studio Device File Explorer the two paths are different

[image]

**Why does it create the directory on a different path?**

Comment: Create a file in one of those directories and see that it appears too in the other one.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. And it appears in the other one.

Comment: Indeed. As they are the same directories. Android is based on Linux and the one is just a link to the other. (Later Windows called it a shortcut).

Comment: So you are saying that both paths point to the same directory... Thanks for the clarification. Why is there a need for a link? Why is it just not a direct pointer? Security issues?

Comment: BTW I'm getting `Unable to load asset...` that's why I searched for the location of my files in the first place. Still getting this error, do I need to declare those files on flutter `assets`?

Comment: I have no idea where you are talking about. If you have problems with files in assets then please make another post about it.

Comment: Do you know the reason for the linking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The two paths are linked to the same directory

According to @blackapps (without further explanation), the two paths are linked to the same directory.

For that reason, when I create new files from one path, I'm able to read them from the other path.

If someone can explain more about the aim of this link, please edit this answer.